# Why does this example use class QTextBrowser; instead of #include <QTextBrowser>

Tags: c++, qt, prototype

I'm using QtCreator and execute a sample code named "Calendar"

I'm new to Qt and C++.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDate>
#include <QMainWindow>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QTextBrowser;
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

Why does this example use class QTextBrowser; prototype statement, instead of #include ?

I executed this code by #include  and delete this macro function. This had no problem.

---

This is from source code

> \macro QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
> \internal
> This macro expands to
> \snippet code/src_corelib_global_qglobal.cpp begin namespace macro
> if \c QT_NAMESPACE is defined and nothing otherwise. If should always
> appear in the file-level scope and be followed by \c QT_END_NAMESPACE
> at the same logical level with respect to preprocessor conditionals
> in the same file.
> As a rule of thumb, \c QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE should appear in all Qt header
> and Qt source files after the last \c{#include} line and before the first
> declaration.
> If that rule can't be followed because, e.g., \c{#include} lines and
> declarations are wildly mixed, place \c QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE before
> the first declaration and wrap the \c{#include} lines in
> \c QT_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE and \c QT_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE.
> When using the \c QT_NAMESPACE feature in user code
> (e.g., when building plugins statically linked to Qt) where
> the user code is not intended to go into the \c QT_NAMESPACE
> namespace, all forward declarations of Qt classes need to
> be wrapped in \c QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE and \c QT_END_NAMESPACE.
> After that, a \c QT_USE_NAMESPACE should follow.
> No further changes should be needed.

and,

> \macro QT_NAMESPACE
> \internal
> If this macro is defined to \c ns all Qt classes are put in a namespace
> called \c ns. Also, moc will output code putting metaobjects etc.
> into namespace \c ns.
> \sa QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE, QT_END_NAMESPACE,
> QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE, QT_USE_NAMESPACE,
> QT_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE, QT_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE,
> QT_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE, QT_END_MOC_NAMESPACE,

I think this comments state that `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` is executed if `QT_NAMESPACE` is defined.

As far as this sample code, `QT_NAMESPACE` is not defined.

And I understand this macro put all Qt classes into a namespace.

But in this sample code, only class `QTextBrowser` is packed by the two macros.

I tried to do this by force,

```
namespace QT_NAMESPACE {
      class QTextBrowser;
}
```

because these are the texts of two macros.

I came to need to write `QT_NAMESPACE::QTextBrowser *editor;`
in class definition.

This can delete newly occured warning  in header file.

But other warnings occur in source file.

```
`editor = new QT_NAMESPACE::QTextBrowser;`
```

Allocation of imcomplete type `QT_NAMESPACE::QTextBrowser`

I want to ask,

why only this class is packed by QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE and QT_END_NAMESPACE?
Are all Qt classes not targeted?

If these macros are executed without problems, new errors and warnings occur in the end. What did the editor think and write this example code?

Comment: This is why macros shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes, I saw these duplicate questions before I put this question. I couldn't have understood the meaning of answers very well... For having conversions namespaces among qt6, qt5, qt4, and qt3?

Comment: You are new to C++. Therefore you should read about why you should use forward declarations rather than include everything, read e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: This question was closed with wrong reference to wrong questions... As far as I understand it, it is not about the QT macros. It is about forward declarations.